# Socket Programming CLIENT SERVER chat application C++

Tags: multithreading, sockets, server, client, chat

I am trying to design a client server model for chat application.Do I need to have two different socket with different port to send and recieve.Actually I have 3 nodes.1 server and 2 client(or slaves).Message passed by client 1 for client 2 will always routed via server.What kind of port and number of socket i should use.Please exaplain I doing all these things in C++ using winsock and pthread API's.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you use TCP (SOCK_STREAM). You need just one socket to for incoming connections. `bind(2)` it to a specific port. You can `accept(2)` any number of connections on it.

Several threads can wait (accept(2)) on the same socket. The OS will dispatch one connection to just one thread ;)

For each outgoing connection you have to create a new socket but you don't have to bind it. The OS will choose an appropriate IP/port itself.

Comment: Thanx for guidance but can you provide some more references to understand this better.If some other references(material) that i can study.